# Make a switch case execute previous cases

Tags: java, switch-statement

My code looks like:

```
    switch(read.nextInt()){
        case 1:
            //do "a" and print the result
            break;
        case 2:
            //do "b" and print the result
            break;
        case 3:
            //do "a" and print the result
            //do "b" and print the result
    }
```

Is there another way to do it without simply copying what's inside case 1 and 2?
I just started my graduation, so I can only use **String** and **Scanner** for this, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tricky one, IMO more readable:

```
int nextInt = read.nextInt();
if (nextInt % 2 == 1) { // or if (nextInt == 1 || nextInt == 3) {
  // do "a" and print the result
}
if (nextInt > 1) {
  // do "b" and print the result
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not allowed to create methods yet,  and this answer really suited, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Define two methods called `doA()` and `doB()` and call them. This way you won't **duplicate your code**. Also are you sure you don't need `break` statements after each `case` statement?

```
    switch(read.nextInt()){
        case 1:
            doA();
            break;
        case 2:
            doB();
            break;
        case 3:
            doA();
            doB();
            break;
        default:
            // do something
            break;
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to write, but there are break statements in my code, thanks!

Comment: Updated the code. It's also good practice to have a default case as well.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this it probably makes sense to create methods for

```
//do "a" and print the result
```

and

```
//do "b" and print the result
```

In case 3 you would just call these methods one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've forgot about 'break'. It makes code "break" from switch statement. If you want in case of '1' & '2' do the same thing and in case of '3' the other thing, you can write:

```
switch(read.nextInt()){
        case 1:
        case 2:
            //do "a" or "b" and print the result
            break; //break from switch statement, otherwise, the code below (yes, I mean "case 3") will be executed too
        case 3:
            //do "a" and print the result
            //do "b" and print the result
    }
```

It is a usual thing to add "break" in the end of "case" block if you don't want the same code block to be executed for several values:

```
switch(n){
        case 1:
            //do something
            break;
        case 2:
            //do other things
            break;
        case 3:
            //more things!
            //you may not write "break" in the last "case" if you want
    }
```